# Select an option in a dynamic select with codeception?

Tags: codeception

```
<select>
    <option value=''>-- Select an Option --</option>
    @foreach ($options as $option)
        <option value='{{ $option->value }}'>{{ $option->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Select the first dynamic option

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$option = $I->grabTextFrom('select option:nth-child(2)');
$I->selectOption("select", $option);
$I->click("Submit");
```

Comment: Is there a way to detect the number of available options?

Comment: Note that you can select the LAST child with: 'select option:last-child' and that you can count back from the end of the list of options with 'select option:nth-last-child(-2)' being the second-last item, etc.

Comment: Also note that for a page with multiple <select> elements on them, you'll have to use a more specific selector instead of just 'select', such as 'select#my-element-id option:nth-child(2)'

Answer (score 7):

I've run into the same issue quite often when starting out with Codeception. Using the recommended answer, I created a helper function in my AcceptanceTester class to make this a little easier.

```
public function selectFromDropdown($selector, $n)
{
    $option = $this->grabTextFrom($selector . ' option:nth-child(' . $n . ')');
    $this->selectOption($selector, $option);
}
```

Where `$n` is the position in the option list.

Then all you have to do is call it like this:

```
$I->selectFromDropdown('select', 1);
```

This has been working for me on pages that have several select's that load their option list based on the selected option of the previous select.

Answer (score 1):

sorry i do not have submit button, in my case i have to select the dropdown element and somehow need to tell the codeception to finish the selection.At the moment i can select but that select is not visible as i suppose the selection is not finished somehow.Below is my code to select the element.

```
$I->selectOption('//*[@class="ng-scope" and @ng-controller="dataIsland"]/*[local-  name()="select"]','partlycloudy');
```